# copying local file to hdfs requires to be on hdfs cluster?

Tags: hdfs

I understand that copyFromLocal or put command is used to copy local files to HDFS. My question is, if one has to be on cluster if we want to run the command to copy files to HDFS?
suppose, I have 3 node cluster as a1,a2 and a3 wherein a1 is the master node and a2 and a3 are the data nodes. 
1. To copy any files to data nodes, I need to login to any of the nodes (a1 ,a2 or a3 )
2. To copy any files to data nodes from any other location outside cluster say machine x1, how can I copy the files from x1 to cluster?

thanks
-Brijesh

Comment: BTW, it is considered polite to accept answers that other people give you (or comment on why it did not solve your problem). I noticed you did not accept an answer to a prior question you posted. When Stackoverflow users notice this behavior they are reticent to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload your files using ssh:

`cat your_local_file_to_upload | ssh username@YOUR_HADOOP_GATEWAY "hadoop dfs -put - hadoopFolderName/file_name_in_hdfs"`

Here, YOUR_HADOOP_GATEWAY is the IP of one of the nodes, or a machine that is configured to act as a gateway to your hadoop cluster

It works for binary files too.

If you want to download files, you can similarly do the following:

`ssh username@YOUR_HADOOP_GATEWAY "hdfs dfs -cat src_path_in_HDFS " > local_dst_path`

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at WebHDFS which is a REST API for interacting with the cluster and usually runs on the same host as the name node.